# CSS3 changing content within an animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm making a breathing circles with CSS animation.

`Circle Expanding = "Breath In"`

`Circle Retains Size = "Hold"`

`Circle Shrinks = "Breath Out"`

Once the circle has reached 100% of the animation I expect the content to switch to "Breath Out" and it never does. How would I get the content to switch from "Hold" to "Breath Out"?

```css
 @import "compass/css3";

  .circle {
    background: purple;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: grow 5s 1;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    line-height: 450px;
    font-size: 60px;
  }

  .text::before {
    -webkit-animation: grow 5s 1;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    content: '';
  }

@-webkit-keyframes grow {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: scale( .5);
      -moz-transform: scale( .5);
      -o-transform: scale( .5);
      -ms-transform: scale( .5);
      transform: scale( .5);
      content: 'Breath In';
    }

    40% {
      -webkit-transform: scale( 1);
      -moz-transform: scale( 1);
      -o-transform: scale( 1);
      -ms-transform: scale( 1);
      transform: scale( 1);
    }

    60% {
      -webkit-transform: scale( 1);
      -moz-transform: scale( 1);
      -o-transform: scale( 1);
      -ms-transform: scale( 1);
      transform: scale( 1);
      content: 'Hold';
    }

    100% {
      -webkit-transform: scale( 0.5);
      -moz-transform: scale( 0.5);
      -o-transform: scale( 0.5);
      -ms-transform: scale( 0.5);
      transform: scale( 0.5);
      content: 'Breath out';
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh9xtu6q/2/

Comment: Interesting, the text does change in Firefox, but doesn't in Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because you have defined the **same animation** for both the main element and the pseudo element and this is creating an issue. Instead you should keep the scale animation on the main element and the content animation on the pseudo element.

*You have defined you animation with only the prefix `-webkit-`, you should remove it*

```css
.circle {
  background: purple;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: grow 5s 1;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  line-height: 450px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.text::before {
  animation: grow-content 5s 1;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  content: '';
}

@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    
    transform: scale( 0.5);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale( 0.5);
  }
}

@keyframes grow-content {
  0%, 40% {
    content: 'Breath In';
  }
  41%, 60% {
    content: 'Hold';
  }
  61%, 100% {
    content: 'Breath out';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer! I have changed the keyframes of the content so that they match better the overall animation

Answer (score 0):

You could add the text using `<span>` tags instead of pseudoelements. This is a lot more CSS, but it will give you more control of the timing, and make it simpler to transition other properties (colour, position etc).

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vn6705qe/2/)

```css
@import "compass/css3";
.circle {
  background: purple;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: grow 5s 1;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  animation: changeText 5s;
}

.text span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.text-in,
.text-hold,
.text-out {
  opacity: 0;
}

.text-in {
  animation: breatheIn 5s infinite;
}

.text-hold {
  animation: breatheHold 5s infinite;
}

.text-out {
  animation: breatheOut 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes breatheIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  15% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  35% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes breatheHold {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  35% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes breatheOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  73% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes grow {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale( .5);
    -moz-transform: scale( .5);
    -o-transform: scale( .5);
    -ms-transform: scale( .5);
    transform: scale( .5);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale( 1);
    -moz-transform: scale( 1);
    -o-transform: scale( 1);
    -ms-transform: scale( 1);
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: scale( 1);
    -moz-transform: scale( 1);
    -o-transform: scale( 1);
    -ms-transform: scale( 1);
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale( 0.5);
    -moz-transform: scale( 0.5);
    -o-transform: scale( 0.5);
    -ms-transform: scale( 0.5);
    transform: scale( 0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="text">
    <span class="text-in">Breath In</span>
    <span class="text-hold">Hold</span>
    <span class="text-out">Breath Out</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a bit difficult to keep relation between all the animation ... when changing something we need to pay attention

Comment: @TemaniAfif True, will depend how much OP wants to be able to adjust timing.

Comment: by the way am pretty sure we can combine all the opacity animations into one and rely on delay but this also will need some reflexion to find the correct values

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah I considered that too. I think sometimes with CSS animations more code is needed to make the effect realistic. Depends how much of a control freak you are :)